# Preventing TortoiseSVN from marking files in the .svn directory as read-only

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN for Windows. Upon commit, TortoiseSVN marks some of the internal files in the ".svn"  subdirectory as read-only. How can I prevent this? It prevents Windows Live Mesh from synchronizing.

Comment: I'm not sure which files are the culprit but if they are stationary you can try to give them also the system attribute. Live Mesh will then stop syncen them.

Comment: I don't see any reason in sycnhronizing these working files in .svn folder. You can have a separate copies of one repository managed independently.

Comment: The previous version of Windows sync was able to sync the .svn directory. That worked perfectly. I could check out something on one computer, modify on a second and commit from a third.

Right now I achieve the same thing by manually removing the read-only flag from all files. That works fine, but I'd rather not have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

All files within the .svn dirs are handled by the Subversion library, meaning **all** svn clients (not just TSVN) mark files in there as readonly. Even the .svn folder itself is marked as readonly and hidden.
There's a reason why those files are marked as readonly and you must not mess with that. SVN relies on that.

Update:
The fact that you're actually trying to sync a working copy implies that you're using version control completely wrong.
It's called a working copy because you should have a copy of it on every station you work with. And you have to use a separate working copy. Not syncing the same working copy.

Comment: Also, synchronization software messes up the checked-out directory if *not* allowed to sync the .svn folder, since it will then only sync the files, whose modified status then will be different of different computers.

Answer (score -1):

So the previous version of Windows Sync... you see what's the problem here. Choose a different sync technology.

The .svn directories are not yours to play with, think of them like the Windows files that are read-only and security protected.

You have a few options:

1. don't sync your WCs. do an individual checkout on each computer.
2. sync the WCs and perform an update after each sync to refresh the .svn files.
3. manually copy the WC from one computer to the other - this works fine in Explorer for example.
4. delete the destination directory before syncing.
5. Stop using crappy sync tools and get a better one. Google says there are too many to list here, but there are a couple of [comparisons](http://sync-software-review.toptenreviews.com/) [available](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/file-sync-backup,review-1060.html) [on the web](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-folder-synchronization-utility.htm).

Comment: Stop using crappy sync tools? Even considering this issue, Windows Live Sync/Mesh is the best I have tried. 

.svn directories are not mine to play with? Synchronizing them works perfectly. The whole idea is to have the directories mirror each other exactly.

Comment: obviously sync doesn't work perfectly or you wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: Two different types of synchronization: between computers I own and between coworkers for collaboration.